# CKEDITOR возвращает пустое значение

Tags: ckeditor

Поставил ckeditor, подключил его все хорошо, все работает.

Но когда я изменяю в нём текст - просто пишу в него "какой то текст", то в таком случае при попытке вернуть его через $('textarea').val() - мне возвращает пустую строку, независимо вносил я туда текст или нет.

Если я в textarea впишу текст

```
<textarea>текст</textarea>
```

Через код

```
$('textarea').val()
```

Я получу "текст"

Но если я допишу после этого еще текст "лалала" и вызову

```
$('textarea').val()
```

Мне вернет: "текст"

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, у Вас поле с CKEditor имеет id `textRu`.
Тогда вот это должно сработать:

```
$('#textRu').val(CKEDITOR.instances.textRu.getData());
```

Comment: Почитал документацию , чуть иначе зделал. 
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery-section-the-.val%28%29-method